# Table search plugins in combination with knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js and generating table with it. Simple, every plugin for table search works just with normal tables, but with tables generated with knockoutjs nothing works. For example:
https://github.com/tommyp/multifilter

Does anybody have solution?

Code:

```
function QuestionGroup(without, added) {
    var self = this;
    self.AllReadyIn = ko.observableArray(added);
    self.CanBeAdded = ko.observableArray(without);

    self.addToGroup = function(without) {
        var temp = without;
        self.CanBeAdded.remove(without);
        self.AllReadyIn.push(temp);
    }

    self.removeFromGroup = function(added) {
        var temp = added;
        self.AllReadyIn.remove(added);
        self.CanBeAdded.push(temp);
    }

}
```

Table and helpers:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="filters">
    <div class="filter-container">
      <input autocomplete="off" class="filter" name="question" placeholder="question" data-col="question">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<table id="withouttes">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: CanBeAdded">
    <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: type"></td>
    <td> <button data-bind="click: $parent.addToGroup">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>
```

Loading for search plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.filter').multifilter({
    'target' : $('#withouttes')
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Knockouts afterRender event on your binding ...

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: CanBeAdded, afterRender: applyMyStuff">
```

applyMyStuff being a function on you ViewModel - something like ...

```
function QuestionGroup(without, added) {
    var self = this;
    self.AllReadyIn = ko.observableArray(added);
    self.CanBeAdded = ko.observableArray(without);

    self.addToGroup = function (without) {
        var temp = without;
        self.CanBeAdded.remove(without);
        self.AllReadyIn.push(temp);
    }

    self.removeFromGroup = function (added) {
        var temp = added;
        self.AllReadyIn.remove(added);
        self.CanBeAdded.push(temp);
    }

    self.applyMyStuff = function() {
         $('.filter').multifilter({
            'target' : $('#withouttes')
          });
    }

}
```

Note: You can then remove the $(document).* script ...